# AArch64 relocation prefixes

Tags: assembly, relocation

I noticed a GNU asm [relocation syntax](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/AArch64_002dRelocations.html) for ARM 64-bit assembly. What are those pieces like `#:abs_g0_nc:` and `:pg_hi21:`? Where are they explained? Is there a pattern to them or are they made up on the go? Where can I learn more?

Comment: They are described [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0056b/IHI0056B_aaelf64.pdf) at section 4.6. There are quite few relocation types, if nobody else will, I may turn that link into an answer later.

Comment: More up to date version of ELF for the Arm 64-bit Architecture (AArch64) is here: https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/master/aaelf64/aaelf64.rst.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Introduction

[ELF64](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/elf-64-gen.pdf) defines two types of relocation entries, called *REL* and *RELA*:

```
typedef struct
{
    Elf64_Addr r_offset;    /* Address of reference */
    Elf64_Xword r_info;     /* Symbol index and type of relocation */
} Elf64_Rel;

typedef struct
{
    Elf64_Addr r_offset;    /* Address of reference */
    Elf64_Xword r_info;     /* Symbol index and type of relocation */
    Elf64_Sxword r_addend;  /* Constant part of expression */
} Elf64_Rela;
```

The scope of each relocation entry is to give the loader (static or dynamic) four pieces of information:

- *The virtual address or the offset of the instruction to patch.*
  This is given by `r_offset`.
- *The runtime address of the symbol accessed.*
  This is given by the higher part of `r_info`.
- *A custom value called addend*
  This value, eventually, as an operand in the expression used to calculate the value that will be written to patch the instruction.
  RELA entries have this value in `r_addend`, REL entries extract it from the relocation site.
- *The relocation type*
  This determines the type of expression uses to calculate the value to patch the instruction. This is encoded in the lower part of `r_info`.

## Relocating

During the relocation phase the loader goes through all the relocation entries and write to the location specified by each `r_offset`, using a formula chosen by the lower part of `r_info` to compute the value to be stored from the *addend* (`r_addend` for RELA) and the symbol address (obtainable from the upper part of `r_info`).

Actually the write part has been simplified, contrary to other architecture where the immediate field of an instruction usually occupy entirely separate byes from the ones used to encode the operation, in ARM, the immediate value is mixed with other encoding information.
So the loader should know what kind of instruction is trying to relocate, if it is an instruction at all<sup>1</sup>, but instead of letting it disassemble the site of relocation, it is the assembler that set the relocation type according to the instruction.

Each relocation symbol can relocate only one or two, encoding-equivalent, instructions.
In specific case the relocation itself even change the type of instruction.

The value compute computed during the relocation is implicitly extended to 64 bits, signed or unsigned based on the relocation type chosen.

## AArch64 relocation

Being ARM a RISC architecture with fixed instruction size, loading full width, i.e. 64 bits, immediate into a register is non trivial as no instruction can have a full width immediate field.

Relocation in AArch64 has to address this issue too, it is actually a two fold problem: first, find the real value that the programmer intended to use (this is the pure relocation part of the problem); second, find a way to put it into a register, since no instruction has a 64 bits immediate field.

The second issue is addressed by using *group relocation*, each relocation type in a group is used to compute a 16 bits part of the 64 bits value, therefore there can only be four relocation type in a group (ranging from *G0* to *G3*).

This slicing into 16 bits comes to fit with the `movk` (move keeping), `movz` (move zeroing) and `movn` (move negating logically).
Other instructions, like `b`, `bl`, `adrp`, `adr` and so on, have a relocation type specially suited for them.

Whenever there is only one, thus unambiguous, possible relocation type for a given instruction that reference a symbol, the assembler can generate the corresponding entry without the need, for the programmer, to specify it explicitly.

Group relocation doesn't fit into this category, they exist to allow the programmer some flexibility, thus are generally explicitly stated. 
In a group, a relocation type can specify if the assembler must perform an overflow check or not.
A *G0* relocation, used to load the lower 16 bits of a value, unless explicitly suppressed, check that the value can fit 16 bits (signed or unsigned, depending on the specific type used). 
The same is true for *G1*, that loading bits 31-16 check that the values can fits 32 bits.
As a consequence *G3* is always non checking as every value fits 64 bits.

Finally, relocation can be used to load integer values into register.
In fact, an address of a symbol is nothing more than an arbitrary integer constant.
Note that `r_addend` is 64 bits wide.

---

<sup>1</sup> If `r_offset` points to a site in a data section the computed value is written as 64 bits word at the location indicated.

### Relocation operators

First of all, some references:

- The ARM document that describes the relocation types for the ELF64 format is [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0056b/IHI0056B_aaelf64.pdf), section 4.6
- A test AArch64 assembly file that, presumably, contains all the relocation operators available to GAS is <s>[here](https://www.slac.stanford.edu/grp/lcls/controls/global/sw/epics/site/cexpsh/Devl/cexp/cexp-CEXP_Release_2_2/binutils-2.23.1/gas/testsuite/gas/aarch64/reloc-insn.s)</s> [here](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/hjl/binutils/+/e30d1ef956c66239f8f23c9aef8f56054215041e/gas/testsuite/gas/aarch64/reloc-insn.s)

## Conventions

Following the ARM document convention we have:

> `S` is the runtime address of the symbol being relocated.
>   `A` is the
>   addend for the relocation.
>   `P` is the address of the relocation site
>   (derived from `r_offset`).
>   `X` is the result of a relocation
>   operation, before any masking or bit-selection operation is applied.
>   `Page(expr)` is the page address of the expression expr, defined as
>   `expr & ~0xFFF`, i.e. `expr` with the lower 12 bits cleared. 
>   `GOT` is
>   the address of the [Global Offset
>   Table](https://www.technovelty.org/linux/plt-and-got-the-key-to-code-sharing-and-dynamic-libraries.html).
>   `GDAT(S+A)` represents a 64-bit entry in the GOT for address S+A. The
>   entry will be relocated at run time with relocation
>   R_AARCH64_GLOB_DAT(S+A).
>   `G(expr)` is the **address** of the GOT
>   entry for the expression expr.
>   `Delta(S)` resolves to the difference
>   between the static link address of `S` and the execution address of
>   `S`. If `S` is the null symbol (ELF symbol index 0), resolves to the
>   difference between the static link address of `P` and the execution
>   address of `P`.
>   `Indirect(expr)` represents the result of calling
>   `expr` as a function.
>   `[msb:lsb]` is a bit-mask operation
>   representing the selection of bits in a value, bounds are inclusive.

## Operators

The relocation name is missing the prefix `R_AARCH64_` for the sake of compactness.

Expressions of the kind *|X|≤2^16* are intended as *-2^16 ≤ X < 2^16*,  **note** the strict inequality on the right.
This is an abuse of notation, called by the constrains of formatting a table.

**Group relocations**

```
Operator    | Relocation name | Operation | Inst | Immediate | Check
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
:abs_g0:    | MOVW_UABS_G0    | S + A     | movz | X[15:0]   | 0≤X≤2^16
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
:abs_g0_nc: | MOVW_UABS_G0_NC | S + A     | movk | X[15:0]   | 
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
:abs_g1:    | MOVW_UABS_G1    | S + A     | movz | X[31:16]  | 0≤X≤2^32
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
:abs_g1_nc: | MOVW_UABS_G1_NC | S + A     | movk | X[31:16]  | 
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
:abs_g2:    | MOVW_UABS_G2    | S + A     | movz | X[47:32]  | 0≤X≤2^48
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
:abs_g2_nc: | MOVW_UABS_G2_NC | S + A     | movk | X[47:32]  | 
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
:abs_g3:    | MOVW_UABS_G3    | S + A     | movk | X[64:48]  | 
            |                 |           | movz |           |
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
:abs_g0_s:  | MOVW_SABS_G0    | S + A     | movz | X[15:0]   | |X|≤2^16
            |                 |           | movn |           |
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
:abs_g1_s:  | MOVW_SABS_G1    | S + A     | movz | X[31:16]  | |X|≤2^32
            |                 |           | movn |           |
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
:abs_g2_s:  | MOVW_SABS_G2    | S + A     | movz | X[47:32]  | |X|≤2^48
            |                 |           | movn |           |
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
```

In the table the *ABS* version is showed, the assembler can pickup the *PREL* (PC relative) or the  *GOTOFF* (GOT relative) version depending on the symbol referenced and the type of output format.

A typical use of this relocation operators is

```
Unsigned 64 bits                      Signed 64 bits   
movz    x1,#:abs_g3:u64               movz  x1,#:abs_g3_s:u64
movk    x1,#:abs_g2_nc:u64            movk  x1,#:abs_g2_nc:u64
movk    x1,#:abs_g1_nc:u64            movk  x1,#:abs_g1_nc:u64
movk    x1,#:abs_g0_nc:u64            movk  x1,#:abs_g0_nc:u64
```

Usually one one checking operator is used, the one that set the highest part.
That's why checking version relocates `movz` only, while the non checking version relocates `movk` (which partially set a register).
*G3* relocated both because it is intrinsically non checking as no value can exceed 64 bits.

The signed versions ends with `_s` and they are always checking.
There is no *G3* version because if a 64 bits value is used the sign if sully specified in the value itself.
They are always used only to set the highest part, as the sign is relevant only there.
They are always checking as an overflow in a signed value make the value meaning less.
These relocations change the type of the instruction to `movn` or `movz` based on the sign of the value, this effectively sign extend the value.

Group relocations, are also available

**PC-relative, 19, 21, 33 bits addresses**

```
Operator    | Relocation name | Operation | Inst | Immediate | Check
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
[implicit]  | LD_PREL_LO19    | S + A - P | ldr  | X[20:2]   | |X|≤2^20
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
[implicit]  | LD_PREL_LO21    | S + A - P | adr  | X[20:0]   | |X|≤2^20
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
[implicit]  | LD_PREL_LO21    | S + A - P | adr  | X[20:0]   | |X|≤2^20
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
:pg_hi21:   | ADR_PREL_PG     | Page(S+A) | adrp | X[31:12]  | |X|≤2^32
            | _HI21           | - Page(P) |      |           |
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
:pg_hi21_nc:| ADR_PREL_PG     | Page(S+A) | adrp | X[31:12]  | 
            | _HI21_NC        | - Page(P) |      |           |
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
:lo12:      | ADD_ABS_LO12_NC | S + A     | add  | X[11:0]   | 
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
:lo12:      | LDST8_ABS_LO12  | S + A     | ld   | X[11:0]   | 
            | _NC             |           | st   |           |
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
:lo12:      | LDST16_ABS_LO12 | S + A     | ld   | X[11:1]   | 
            | _NC             |           | st   |           |
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
:lo12:      | LDST32_ABS_LO12 | S + A     | ld   | X[11:2]   | 
            | _NC             |           | st   |           |
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
:lo12:      | LDST64_ABS_LO12 | S + A     | prfm | X[11:3]   | 
            | _NC             |           |      |           |
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
:lo12:      | LDST128_ABS     | S + A     | ?    | X[11:4]   | 
            | _LO12_NC        |           |      |           |
```

The `:lo12:` change meaning depending on the size of the data the instruction is handling (e.g. `ldrb` uses `LDST8_ABS_LO12_NC`, `ldrh` uses `LDST16_ABS_LO12_NC`).

A GOT relative version of these relocations also exists, the assembler will pickup the right one.

**Control flow relocations**

```
Operator    | Relocation name | Operation | Inst | Immediate | Check
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
[implicit]  | TSTBR14         | S + A - P | tbz  | X[15:2]   | |X|≤2^15
            |                 |           | tbnz |           |  
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
[implicit]  | CONDBR19        | S + A - P | b.*  | X[20:2]   | |X|≤2^20
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
[implicit]  | JUMP26          | S + A - P | b    | X[27:2]   | |X|≤2^27
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
[implicit]  | CALL26          | S + A - P | bl   | X[27:2]   | |X|≤2^27
------------+-----------------+-----------+------+-----------+----------
```

### Epilogue

I couldn't find an official documentation.
The tables above have been reconstructed from the GAS test case and the ARM document explaining the type of relocations available for AArch64 compliant ELFs.

The tables doesn't show all the relocations present in the ARM document, as most of them are complementary versions, picked up by the assembler automatically.

A section with examples would be great, but I don't have an ARM GAS.
In the future I may extend this answer to include examples of assembly listings and relocations dumps.

Comment: Thanks for the write up. I appreciate you're touching up a very broad topic. I think much of what goes into binutils is esoteric, and it's a shame not all of this is thoroughly written down. Too late in my career to make a switch now!

Comment: The link https://www.slac.stanford.edu/grp/lcls/controls/global/sw/epics/site/cexpsh/Devl/cexp/cexp-CEXP_Release_2_2/binutils-2.23.1/gas/testsuite/gas/aarch64/reloc-insn.s does not work anymore.

Comment: @pogojotz Thank you. I found another copy.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wish you have much more votes than now, your answer is brilliant.