# How to find the offset value of @PAGE/@PAGEOFF

Tags: assembly, llvm, arm64

Looking into a disassembly code, I saw the instructions like:

```
adrp x8,l066@PAGE
add x8,x8,l066@PAGEOFF
```

Are they the offset labels being defined somewhere? And how to find the value of them?

Comment: Might they just be the [relocation types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570495/aarch64-relocation-prefixes/38608738#38608738)?

Answer (score 2):

`@page` and `@pageoff` are assembler directives to calculate the offset at link time.  `@page` takes the position independent 4k page offset of the symbol and uses the PC to convert it into an absolute page address.  `@pageoff` gives the offset into the page that the symbol is located.  Together they are able to generate a 64-bit address in a position-independent way.

Comment: So, is it possible to find them by ida or hopper? I mean not by the way of examining them at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen that disassembly style before, but I'd automatically assume that `l066` is a label that the disassembler has inferred, for which it is also annotating the appropriate relocations [as Margaret says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711058/how-to-find-the-offset-value-of-page-pageoff#comment64806568_38711058). In other words, it's effectively [`adrl x8, l066`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0801f/dom1395139165628.html).

Comment: Those are generated by `otool -Vtdj -arch arm64`.