# How do we store large decimal/hex value in ARMs?

Tags: arm64

I run into a roadblock and not sure where to go from here. I know MOV can only store a maximum of 0-65535 in decimal. However, the value I'm trying to store is 30,402,460.

I was going to use MVN as some source mention that can store bigger number in this format:
MVN X9, #(num), #(num). However 30402460 / 110 = only equals 276,386 which is still above the decimal value of 65535 so I can't use MVN.

My question is; how do we store 30402460 to X9?

Comment: You are not running with 16-bit processing; your tag says "arm64".  65535 is the largest unsigned 16 bit integer.   Looking here:https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100076/0100/a64-instruction-set-reference/a64-general-instructions/mov--to-or-from-sp-?lang=en, MOV handles 32 or 64 bits.  So I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: I am not familiar with that site.   What really matters is how it works on your hardware.

Comment: I see... I’ll get back to you on this. As I mention I tried mov x9, #30402460 with no luck. Tried with add x9, x9, #30402460. The resource that you listed there mention it’s an alternative to the add instruction.

Comment: That could be done by loading values from memory pool `ldr x9, =30402460`. About loading by `MOVZ`, `MOVK`, `MOVN` you could read elaborated answer of @Peter Cordes here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55112772/lower16-upper16-for-aarch64-absolute-address-into-register

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MOV` is not a real instruction. It's an alias that will be turned into either `MOVZ`, `MOVN` or `ORR` as appropriate. But each of those have their own constraints:

- `MOVZ` can load an arbitrary 16 bits, left-shifted by 0, 16, 32 or 48 bits. So you can only use this for values with 48 bits of all zeroes.
- `MOVN` does the same as `MOVZ`, but inverts the register value. So you can only use this for values with at least 48 bits of all ones.
- `ORR` can construct a really complicated bitmask which, as best as I can tell, can be any sequence of consecutive runs of zeroes, ones, zeroes or ones, zeroes, ones, repeated by any power of two that is a divisor of the register width. So you can load values like `0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`, `0xfffffff00fffffff` and `0x18`, but not values like `0x0` or `0x5`.

The value 30402460 matches none of these constraints. The usual practice for loading such values is to use `MOVZ` followed by `MOVK`, the latter of which allows replacing 16 bits of a register without changing the other bits. So in your case:

```
movz x9, 0x1cf, lsl 16
movk x9, 0xe79c
```

Comment: Tysm for the information. Can you explain the math behind movz x9, 0x1cf, lsl 16 & movk x9, 0xe79c?

Comment: @KojTug `0x1cfe79c == 30402460`