# Understanding ARM relocation (example: str x0, [tmp, #:lo12:zbi_paddr])

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64, linker-scripts

I found this line of assembly in [zircon kernel start.S](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/a3e235192ed4f3254a00eacd5015466599f9e97c/zircon/kernel/arch/arm64/start.S#81)

```
str     x0, [tmp, #:lo12:zbi_paddr]
```

for ARM64. I also found that `zbi_paddr` is defined in C++:

```
extern paddr_t zbi_paddr;
```

So I started looking about what does `#:lo12:` mean.

I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/38608738/6655884 which looks like a great explanation, but it does not explain the very basic: what is a rellocation and why some things are needed.

I guess that since `zbi_paddrr` is defined in `start.S` and used in C++ code, since `start.S` generates on object file `start.o` with addresses starting at 0, the linking process will have to reallocate all addresses there to addresses in the final executable file.

In order to keep track of the symbols that need rellocation, ELF stores these structs, as said in the answer:

```
typedef struct
{
    Elf64_Addr r_offset;    /* Address of reference */
    Elf64_Xword r_info;     /* Symbol index and type of relocation */
} Elf64_Rel;

typedef struct
{
    Elf64_Addr r_offset;    /* Address of reference */
    Elf64_Xword r_info;     /* Symbol index and type of relocation */
    Elf64_Sxword r_addend;  /* Constant part of expression */
} Elf64_Rela;
```

So for example, `r_offset` would store the address of `zbi_paddr` in the final executable. Then, when the program is loaded, the loader looks on these structs and then fills the address of `zbi_paddr` from the C++ code.

After that I completely missed the need for those things like `S`, `A`, `P`, `X` and `abs_g0_s` and `lo12`. He says it's related to instructions not being able to insert 64 bits into registers. Can someone give me more context? I can't understand, there are already ways to insert 64 bits into registers. And how this is related to reallocation?

Comment: arm instructions are fixed size, there is simply no room to load a full 64 bit immediate. You either load from memory (literal pool) or you put it together from parts. The various relocation types are tailored to particular instruction formats. The `STR` instruction you showed only allows for a 12 bit offset.

Comment: It's important to read this in conjunction with the `adrp` instruction that preceded it.  The [gas manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/AArch64_002dRelocations.html#AArch64_002dRelocations) has an example of what's being done here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The underlying issue is that ARM64 instructions are all 32 bits in size, which limits the number of bits of immediate data that can be encoded in any one instruction.  You certainly cannot encode 64 bits of address, or even 32 bits.

The code and static data of the kernel can be expected to be well under 4 GB, so in order to store data in the static variable `zbi_paddr`, the programmer can write the following two instructions (including the preceding one which you omitted but is crucial).  Note that `tmp` is a macro defined above as `x9`, so the code expands to:

```
adrp    x9, zbi_paddr
str     x0, [x9, #:lo12:zbi_paddr]
```

Now when linking occurs, the linker will know the layout of the entire kernel, and the relative locations of all symbols.  This scheme supports position-independent code, so the absolute addresses need not be known, but we will certainly know the *displacement* between `zbi_paddr` and the `adrp` instruction above, which will fit in a signed 32-bit value, as well as the offset of `zbi_paddr` within its 4KB page (since the kernel will necessarily be loaded at a page-aligned address).

So bits 12 and higher of this displacement will be encoded into the `adrp` instruction, which has a 21-bit immediate field.  `adrp` will sign-extend it, add it to the corresponding bits of the program counter, and place the result in `x9`.  Then `x9` will contain bits 63-12 of the absolute address of `zbi_paddr`, with the low 12 bits being zeroed.

The 12-bit offset of `zbi_paddr` within its page will be encoded into the 12-bit immediate field of the `str` instruction.  It adds this immediate to the value in `x9`, which will then yield the address of `zbi_paddr`, and it stores `x0` at that address.  So we have managed to store a value in `zbi_paddr` with just two instructions.

To support this, the object file produced by assembling our code needs to instruct the linker that bits 32-12 of the displacement need to be inserted into the `adrp` instruction, and bits 11-0 of the address of `zbi_paddr` need to be inserted into the `str` instruction.  These instructions to the linker are what relocations are; they'll contain a reference to the symbol whose address is to be encoded (here `zbi_paddr`) and what specifically is to be done with it.  ELF supports relocations specifically designed for these instructions, that put just the right bits in the right place in the instruction word.

It's true that there are other ways to get a 64-bit value into a register.  For instance, it can be placed in the literal pool, which is an area of data close enough to the corresponding code that it can be reached with a single `ldr` instruction (with PC-relative displacement).  You could have a relocation telling the linker to insert the absolute address of `zbi_paddr` in the literal pool.  But loading it requires an additional memory access, which is slower than `adrp`; moreover, the 8 bytes of literal, plus the `ldr`, plus the `str` to actually do the store, add up to a total of 16 bytes of memory needed.  The `adrp/str` approach only needs 8, and it works better with position-independent code, where the linker may not actually know the absolute address of `zbi_paddr`.

If you don't like the load from memory, you can get the absolute address of `zbi_paddr` into a register with up to four `mov/movk` instructions, loading 16 bits at a time.  There are relocations for that, too.  But with the final `str`, we are using up to 20 bytes of code; executing five instructions takes more clock cycles than two; and there's still a problem with position-independent code.

As such, `adrp/str`, with `:lo12:` as noted, is the standard accepted method for accessing a global or static variable.  If you want to load instead of store, you use `adrp/ldr`.  And if you want the address of `zbi_paddr` in a register, you do

```
adrp x9, zbi_paddr
add x9, x9, #:lo12:zbi_paddr
```

The `add` instruction also supports a 12-bit immediate, precisely for this purpose.

These features are explained in the [GNU assembler manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/AArch64_002dRelocations.html#AArch64_002dRelocations).