# how +/- 4GB range is calculated for ADRP

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64, instruction-set

I do understand, both ADR and ADRP is for PC relative addressing where with 20 bit of immediate address (for ADR) , it can point upto +/-1 MB (2^20) of address range but how +/- 4GB is calculated for ADRP.

Apart from that I have simple snippet:

```
int g =1;
main()
{
  return g;
}
```

After disassembling it:

```
adrp.o:     file format elf64-littleaarch64
```

Disassembly of section `.text`:

```
0000000000000000 <main>:
0:  90000000    adrp    x0, 0 <main>
4:  b9400000    ldr w0, [x0]
8:  d65f03c0    ret
```

How do the addresses are patched in, and is the address of main at offset > 1MB ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what your question is, but check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/64841097/634919 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41906688/what-are-the-semantics-of-adrp-and-adrl-instructions-in-arm-assembly for info about how `adrp` is used.  The appropriate displacements get patched in by the linker; it looks like you're disassembling the object file before linking has been done, so you don't see this.

Comment: The other note is that the low 12 bits of the address get patched into the 12-bit offset field of the `ldr` instruction.  21 bits of immediate displacement in `adrp`, plus 12 bits of offset in `ldr`, gives 33 bits, which is where your +/- 4 GB comes from.

Comment: So this convention (code model) is designed for a program in which `g` *could* be more than 1 MB, but less than 4 GB, away from the instruction in `main` where it is loaded.  Whether it actually is or not would not be known until the program is linked; the compiler doesn't know whether this file is all of the program, or whether there might be a ton of other code and data in other source/object files.  In this particular program it surely isn't, so simpler code might have been sufficient, but the compiler didn't know that.

Comment: The RISC V compilers & linkers do what is being called linker "relaxation", which allows the linker to shorten the code sequence when it is not actually needed.  (Quite involved and requires a lot more (i.e internal) relocations to be forwarded to the linker for final adjustment.)