# How does one tell if the ascii character inside a register is equal to the ascii character inside of another register in 64-bit ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64

I'm attempting to load the first letter of a string into the register W2, then compare the value inside that register to the value inside of another register (W5). In the program below, the code refuses to branch even though both characters in each registers are equal. How can I get the code to branch.

```
     .data 

string: .asciz "Hello"       // Loads string the ascii character "Hello"

charH:  .asciz "H"           // Initializes charH with 'H'

    .global _start      // Provide program with starting address to linker
    .text

_start:

    LDR X0,=string  // Loads the string "Hello" into X0
    LDR W5,=charH   // Loads the character "H" into W5

 // Should Load the first letter of string into the W2 register and then post-increments the pointer to the next byte of the string
    
    LDRB    W2, [X0], #1    

    CMP W2, W5       // Compares W2 with W5
    B.EQ equalsH     // Branches if both equal  

end:
    
    MOV X0, #0  // Use 0 return code

    MOV X8, #93 // Service command code 93 to terminate the program

    SVC 0       // Call linux to terminate

    .end

// The Goal is to get the condition to branch here! "equalsH"

    equalsH:

    // ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LDR W5,=charH` doesn't load the byte `'H'` into W5.  Rather, it loads the low 32 bits of the *address* of the label `charH` into W5.

If you wanted to get the actual character that is stored in memory at that address, you would need another load.  (And use the full 64-bit address to begin with.)

```
LDR X5, =charH
LDRB W5, [X5]
```

However, ARM64 has move-immediate instructions that can handle any value up to 16 bits.  Thus you can drop `charH` altogether and simply do

```
MOV W5, 'H'
```

For that matter, since `CMP` can also take an immediate (up to 12 bits), you could skip W5 altogether, and after loading W2 just do:

```
CMP W2, 'H'
B.EQ equalsH
```

---

On another note, `LDR X0, =string` isn't really the best way to get the address of `string`.  It's better to use `adr` or `adrp` so that you have position-independent code.  See [Understanding ARM relocation (example: str x0, [tmp, #:lo12:zbi_paddr])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64838776/understanding-arm-relocation-example-str-x0-tmp-lo12zbi-paddr/64841097#64841097) for an overview.  But in brief, with two instructions and no literal pool data, you can both compute the address and do the load.

```
ADRP X0, string
LDRB W2, [X0, #:lo12:string]
```

This doesn't post-increment X0 as your code does, but your code never actually uses the incremented value anyway.

Comment: I had guessed that an`LDR X0, =string` pseudo-instruction would assemble to a normal PC-relative `adrp`/`add`, but with aarch64 GNU Binutils 2.37 it does indeed assemble to a PC-relative load from a literal pool.  Same with `clang -target arm64 -c`.  I think GAS for 32-bit ARM will use relative addressing or `movw`/`movk` if available for `ldr reg, =symbol`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes, I've heard that there are assemblers that, when applicable, can "optimize" an `LDR Xn, =value` into `MOV` or `ADRP` or what have you.  But I've only tried GAS, which always gives you a load from the literal pool.

Comment: I just tried with the 32-bit equivalent, and current GAS and clang don't do it there, either.   I think what I'm remembering is that GAS and clang will optimize *numeric* constants like `ldr r0, =0x12` into `mov` (but other toolchains still always `ldr`).  For some reason only clang will optimize `ldr r0, =0x1234` into `movw` even in ARM mode, not GAS.  I thought I'd seen movw/movk from some toolchain, but probably my memory was mixing that up with C->asm code-gen from compilers on Godbolt avoiding `ldr reg, =symbol` or `=0x...` in the first place for some `-mcpu=` options but not others.